# How can I return only end nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to return just the end nodes of a match that can be either one or two path segments away. For example:

```
start me=node(1) 
match me-[:FRIEND_OF]->parent, me-[:FRIEND_OF]->child-[:CHILD_OF]->parent 
return parent;
```

I want only the parents returned, but in some cases the child is my friend. How would I get just the parents returned?

Comment: putting an example graph on console.neo4j.org would help. the part that has me confused is the "either one or two paths away".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding this will help. I'm not entirely clear on your example. This filters out "parents" who are children.

```
...
where not(()-[:CHILD_OF]->parent)
return parent;
```